# Windows 10 Биос Приватность

Tags: windows

Как может использоваться ключ windows 10, вшитый в биос, против его пользователя? То есть какую информацию о пользователе он может предоставить. И доп. вопрос: как Microsoft может использовать этот ключ в своих целях (для слежки, сбора информации и т.д.)?

Comment: Вся информация о пользователе, которая позволяет его идентифицировать, может быть использована против него. Она может быть свидетельством принадлежности оборудования, доказывать факт использования сетевых ресурсов с данного устройства, являться частью метки идентификации и т.д. Корысть может быть **любая** и чья угодно. Я рекомендовал бы уточнить вопрос.

Comment: Да, точно, извиняюсь, сейчвс дополню

Comment: В самом ключе не может быть никакой информации о пользователе. Это просто серийный номер с криптографической защитой (подписью). Но конечно с момента продажи устройства можно начинать за этим серийным номером собирать в базы данных самого MS и сторонних лиц любую информацию, которую удастся получить о пользователе. С тем же успехом можно использовать любой другой сохраняющийся во времени идентификатор. Так что по сравнению с другими идентификаторами у вшитого в bios ключа единственное преимущество, что его гораздо сложнее переписать

Comment: Если вопрос именно о ключе, зашитом в BIOS. То не факт, что MS использует его для идентификации. Для этого она может использовать уникальный идентификатор установленной ОС, не привязываясь к железу. Может использовать контрольную сумму BIOS, ID- жесткого диска и т.д. Однако исходя из положений [политики](https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-gb/privacystatement), следует: MS однозначно идентифицирует пользователя (либо его устройство) и собирает сведения о его активности. Цели обработки просты и ясны: заработать на информации о пользователе. А вот угроз и последствий небрежного хранения инфы много!

Comment: А если я использую линукс, этот ключ никак не может помочь собирать данные?

Comment: находясь в Web Вы идентифицируемы по другим признакам. Существует множество крупных сервисов слежения за активностью пользователей Web-сайтов. И никто им не запрещает продавать эту информацию друг другу, либо иным корпорациям. Для этого им совершенно **не нужно** значение вшитой последовательности символов BIOS-а Вашего компьютера. Если же речь идёт об экосистеме MS, то она (как вы понимаете) закрыта для исследований. Поэтому о том, что там происходит можно строить любые предположения. Основываясь на известных фактах работы: системы телеметрии, системы обновлений, системы лицензирования и пр.

Comment: спасибо за ответ!